# ajax call not working in firefox and chrome but working in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

Below is javascript which is being called in  `$(document).ready` function. In IE its working fine and returning the records where as in firefox and chrome its giving error. But error not giving any details. It just says ready state = 0, status = error and responseText is blank.

```
var surl = serviceUrl + trainingService + "GetLastUpdateDate/";

$.ajax({
    url: surl,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert("SUCCESS:  " + data.d.length);
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
        alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
        alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

As someone asked in the comments below is the screenshot of firebug debugger, as I mentioned earlier it doesn't give much details.

[image: firebug watch window]

Comment: Sounds like a good time to consult the "Network" tab in Chrome Developer tools (hit F12) and see what the ajax call is actually doing.

Comment: Wow, IE works but FF and Google Chrome no?!This is new! rsrs

Comment: We need a "what does the console say" song.

Comment: When you have dataType: 'json' it seems that you need to return valid JSON, otherwise it won't execute the "success" function.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, its because i was using `<button onClick="doSomething()">button</button>` which was causing the page to do a postback instead using `<input type="button" onClick="doSomething()" value="button"/>` worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Is your ajax call a request to the same domain? If not, you should use JSONP instead of JSON.

```
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/
```

Also, I have seen where IE will work and Chrome and Firefox will not if the ajax request is not of the same protocol as the requesting page (if the page is https and the ajax call is http for example).

And last, do you have any ad blocking plugins installed on Firefox and Chrome that aren't installed on IE? I've seen where some ad blocking plugins will also block ajax requests.

Comment: No there are no plugins installed on Firefox and Chrome. I tried this on same domain and cross domain as well but in both the cases its not working.